# XMLHttpRequest sending post request and receiving 2 response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i press enterAction I get weird response so when i open firebug it shows me that i am getting a post response and a get response (it doesn't happens always but when i leave page idle for some minutes lets say 5 or 10 it is kind of random)

HTML Code

```
<form id="post-form" method="post" action="/v2/TheNet/ajax/ajax.php" onsubmit="return false">
    <textarea id="post_message_id" placeholder="Write something..." name="publish">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="post_message" name="action">
</form>
```

JS Code

```
$(function () {

    shiftEnterNewLine('post_message_id', enterAction);

    $('#post-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
function enterAction() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("post-form"));

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                $('#post_message_id').val('');               
            }
        };
        //initiate request
        xhr.open('post', '/v2/ajax/TheNet/ajax.php', true);
        xhr.send(form);
    }

function shiftEnterNewLine(id, action) {
    $('#' + id).keydown(function (e) {
        //enter
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            action();
            // console.log("a");
            // // shift
        }
    });
}
```

Picture of response >

[image]
[image]
I am suppose to get the post response only, do you guys know what's going on?

**ANSWER:**
I think the jquery was fine but my php code was redirecting to that folder

Comment: Could be a redirect, check the headers of the POST response

Comment: Please, how `enterAction()` is called ?

Comment: I just did it, and sorry for the delayed reply

Answer (score 1):

add **onsubmit="return false"** in tag **form**:

```
<form id="post-form" method="post" action="/v2/TheNet/ajax/ajax.php" onsubmit="return false">
    <textarea id="post_message_id" placeholder="Write something..." name="publish">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="post_message" name="action">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i would like to know what return false mean in submit?

Comment: in tag form: at event onsubmit: code here do when before submit, return false will stop submit

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code. This will solve your problem

```
<form id="post-form" method="post" action="/v2/TheNet/ajax/ajax.php" onsubmit="return false">
    <textarea id="post_message_id" placeholder="Write something..." name="publish">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="post_message" name="action">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering my jquery code was correct but my php code was redirecting when token expired to `header('Localtion: .')` i just needed to modify this.